# ActiveWeb view - <@compress single_line=true>

Tags: javalite, activeweb

I wonder what is the following declaration/macro used for (I'm rendering a custom JSON response):

```
<@compress single_line=true>
{
  attribute_1: ${my_model.attribute_1},
  attribute_2: ${my_model.attribute_2},
  attribute_3: ${my_model.attribute_3},
}
</@compress>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of the FreeMarker, please see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html